# How to make app running on a device which version differs from Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

After I downloaded DeviceSupport file(it downloads as a folder, though Archive utility is in place) and put it in Xcode(as far as I remember, it was closed beforehand), I couldn't find new versions in deployment target. But Xcode didn't complain about it. It gave me the following error: "Failed to prepare device for development". And, to my understanding, it means that compatibility issue is probably solved, because it refused to run before saying that versions were incompatible. So, how to make app running on a device which version differs from Xcode

I tried to reboot both a computer and an iPhone and unpair watchOS from the iPhone, but nothing worked.

Comment: Let’s start with versions of DeviceSupport. To those who has more experience with DeviceSupport than I do, do new versions display in deployment target in Xcode? Do you need to manually change version of supported device in version plist or it’s updated automatically?

Comment: Can’t write in version.plist. Is there any sense to make a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, because it doesn’t eliminate the error, and it doesn’t show you any logs in the console, but, nonetheless, it allows you to run your app on the phone. It goes as follows:

1. When your device is connected - click on it, then go to “Add additional simulators” -> “Devices”
2. Run the app
3. Search for your app in Finder
4. When you find it, drag it to “Installed apps” in the “Devices” section.

And here you go!

Comment: By the way, I found the solution here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671101